# Finding trouble to change installed font using iText library

Tags: java, fonts, itext

So I was trying to use this font I installed called "Tengwar Quenya-1 Regular" and it didn't work, it keep writing de PDF document with the default font. So I tried to use the downloaded file, by using EMBED method, and it is still printing the default font, I wondering if anyone had tried this before, and could tell me what I am doing wrong. Check the code:

```
public void testePdf(){
    Document document = new Document();

    String filename = "C:\\Users\\Marcelo\\Downloads\\tengwar_quenya\\QUENCAP1.TFF";
    FontFactory.register(filename);
    Font fonte = FontFactory.getFont(filename, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
            new FileOutputStream(filename+ "HelloWorld.pdf"));

        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("A Hello World PDF document.", fonte));
        document.close(); // no need to close PDFwriter?

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It compiles fine, just not with the font I selected. If it is a glyph instead of a caracter, will it be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Googled for the font you mention. I have downloaded it and I have made a small SSCCE that you can download here: [TengwarQuenya1](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/fonts/TengwarQuenya1)

This is the code:

```
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/QUENCAP1.TTF";

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
    document.open();
    Font f1 = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12);
    document.add(new Paragraph("A Hello World PDF document.", f1));
    document.close();
}
```

This is the result: [tengwarquenya1.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/tengwarquenya1.pdf)

[image]

I'm not sure what the resulting text means, but it doesn't look like the default font to me.

In other words: I can't reproduce the problem. Note that you don't need to register a font if you pass its file path to the `FontFactory`. Obviously, my font path is different from yours. I think that yours is wrong. Try putting the ".TTF" file in another location.

Comment: And if instead of text between quotes, I wished to put a char[][], would you know how to do that?

Comment: Why the double array? Did you read the documentation? Are you referring to the question "How to create a table based on a two-dimensional array?" in my free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](https://leanpub.com/itext_so)? Because that's what it looks like...

Comment: I have been looking all over the internet and file documentatio for this

Comment: And now you have found it ;-) Or isn't that what you meant by your comment? If not, you'll have to explain what you mean when you say *I wished to put a char[]*. Also: read the answer to the final question in the book. People who say "I have been looking all over the internet" can trigger responses that hurt their feelings.

Comment: Bruno, I already have the array, but I can't print it. I tried but couldn't take a look at your book.

Comment: Solved my problem with, what we call in Brazil, a "gambiarra". And Bruno, got your book, read and now i am going to buy it becouse it was very interesting!

Comment: Don't buy it. It's free!